# Parsing query SQL-Like to match open and closed brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
((one = WORD) AND (two != 2) AND (three > 3) AND (four >= 4) AND (five < 5) AND (six <= 6) AND (seven IN (seven1, seven2)) AND (eight LIKE 'like'))
```

I need a pattern (Java) for matching all the groups, that pay attention to the inner group for the IN operator. I need a result like this

```
one = WORD
two != 2
three > 3
four >= 4
five < 5
six <= 6
seven IN (seven1, seven2)
eight LIKE 'like'
```

A single pattern that match from `(` to the next first `)` is not fine, because for the IN operator there is a inner group

Thank you

Comment: I'm not near my compiler so I can't test this, but have you tried using the String `split()` method with the `"AND"` argument? This should return you an array of Strings as you want, then for each string you can trim it and remove the leading and trailing characters (should be parentheses)

Comment: What about if a value contains the word `AND`? Like `(one = LAND)`

Comment: this might be of interest ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java

Comment: Thank you, please take a look to my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java), i wrote this sample code

```
String string = "((one = WORD) AND (two != 2) AND (three > 3) AND (four >= 4) AND (five < 5) AND (six <= 6) AND (seven IN (seven1, seven2)) AND (eight LIKE '1,2,3'))";

long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*|\\([^()]*\\))*\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());

long stop_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time " + (stop_time - start_time) + "ms");
```

The output is perfect, but the performance is embarrassing, 7-8 seconds

```
(one = WORD)
(two != 2)
(three > 3)
(four >= 4)
(five < 5)
(six <= 6)
(seven IN (seven1, seven2))
(eight LIKE '1,2,3')

Time 8017ms
```

**EDIT**: For now solved like this

```
string = string.substring(2, string.length() - 2);
String[] split = string.split("\\) AND \\(");

for (String s : split)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: May be you could use a different approach: http://www.strchr.com/expression_evaluator