# Java detect first level "if" conditions in a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect first level "if" conditions in a piece of text.
Example text:

```
if (a == 5) {
    method1();
    method2()
}
if (a == 6) {
    method1();
    if (a < 2) {
        method3();
    }
}
if (a >= 8 && a <= 13) {
    method5(a);
    int[] b = new int[a];
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            b[i] = i * 4;
            continue;
        }
        b[i] = i * 2;
    }
    method4(b);
}
if (a > 16) {
    method6();
}
```

This is what I got so far:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text = "if (a == 5) {\n\tmethod1();\n\tmethod2()\n}\nif (a == 6) {\n\tmethod1();\n\tif (a < 2) {\n\t\tmethod3();\n\t}\n}\nif (a >= 8 && a <= 13) {\n\tmethod5(a);\n\tint[] b = new int[a];\n\tfor(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {\n\t\tif (i == 0) {\n\t\t\tb[i] = i * 4;\n\t\t\tcontinue;\n\t\t}\n\t\tb[i] = i * 2;\n\t}\n\tmethod4(b);\n}\nif (a > 16) {\n\tmethod6();\n}";
    for(String line : text.split("if (.*) \\{")) {
      System.out.println("Line: " + line);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Line: 
Line: 
    method1();
    method2()
}

Line: 
    method1();

Line: 
        method3();
    }
}

Line: 
    method5(a);
    int[] b = new int[a];
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

Line: 
            b[i] = i * 4;
            continue;
        }
        b[i] = i * 2;
    }
    method4(b);
}

Line: 
    method6();
}
```

It also prints nested ifs. I only want the first level ones. And the if will disappear when printing the line. I want the if to show too.

I basically want to group all first level ifs into one string. Can some one help me with this?

Comment: Regexps are not the right tool to do that

Comment: Can you also tell me what I should use instead?

Comment: a scanner and a parser

Comment: Can you be more specific? You mean a Java parser or something?

Comment: Yes. There are a few Java parsers out there.

Comment: Apparently, you would only need to support a subset of the language

Comment: Alright. I'll try a Java parser today and post the answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to add why regular expression is not the right tool: regular expression can only detect regular languages (hence the name), but this is a context-free language (because of the brackets that must be matched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that you have to deal with nested brackets, the appropriate regex will be hard to maintain as described here in SO [How to match string within parentheses (nested) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17759264/4098311)

My solution is:

1. Do some preprocessing to replace the nested brackets
2. Capture the if content using regex
3. Finally, postprocessing to hand over the real brackets

```
package demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser {

    private static final char OPENED_BRACKET = '{';
    private static final char CLOSED_BRACKET = '}';
    private static final String OPENED_BRACKET_REPLACOR = "##OPENED_BRACKET_REPLACOR##";
    private static final String CLOSED_BRACKET_REPLACOR = "##CLOSED_BRACKET_REPLACOR##";

    private static final String REGEX    = "\\{((.|\\n|\r|\t)*?)\\}";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

    public String preprocessing(String origin) {
        StringBuilder replaced = new StringBuilder();
        int opened = 0;
        for(int index = 0 ; index < origin.length() ; index++) {
            char current_char = origin.charAt(index);
            String processed  = Character.toString(current_char);

            if(current_char == OPENED_BRACKET) {
                if(opened++ > 0) {
                    processed = OPENED_BRACKET_REPLACOR; 
                }
            }

            else if(current_char == CLOSED_BRACKET) {
                if(--opened > 0) {
                    processed = CLOSED_BRACKET_REPLACOR; 
                }
            }

            replaced.append(processed);
        }
        return replaced.toString();
    }

    public List<String> extract(String source) {
        final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(source);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public List<String> postprocessing(List<String> source) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String src: source) {
            result.add(src.replaceAll(OPENED_BRACKET_REPLACOR, Character.toString(OPENED_BRACKET))
                          .replaceAll(CLOSED_BRACKET_REPLACOR, Character.toString(CLOSED_BRACKET)));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        String code = "if (a == 6) { method1(); if (a < 2) { method3(); } }if (a == 5) { method1();\n\r" +
                      " method2() }";
        String preprocessed = parser.preprocessing(code);
        List<String> extracted = parser.extract(preprocessed);
        List<String> postprocessed = parser.postprocessing(extracted);
        for(String ifContent: postprocessed) {
            System.out.println("Line: " + ifContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Will ouptput:

> Line:  method1(); if (a < 2) { method3(); }
>  
>   Line:  method1();
>
> method2()

Comment: Nice, a pure Java solution. I like this. There's only one thing left. How can I get the if condition for each if content?

Comment: @Displee you didn't asked for :) but you can play with regex in my solution: something like `private static final String REGEX = "if\((.*?)\) \\{((.|\\n|\r|\t)*?)\\}";` (not tested) and you will get the condiftion in matcher.group(1) and the if body in `matcher.group(2)` don't forget to upvote or mark as resolved to help other people....

Comment: Well, at the bottom of my question it clearly states "And the if will disappear when printing the line. I want the if to show too.".

But I guess you misread that. Anyways, I will try this when I'm home.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got it working. Ended up with: `if (.*) \{((.|
|
| )*?)}`. Thanks again!