# JavaScript RegExp: match all specific chars ignoring nested parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

Actually I need to split this line by `whitespaces` ignoring those in parentheses (could be nested):

```
var string = 'a b c(a b c) d(a (b) c)'
```

Into this array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c(a b c)', 'd(a (b) c)']
```

The essence of my task is to get list of all variables and function calls separated by whitespaces

So, splitting by whitespaces, everything in parentheses should be ignored

I understand how it is godless to ask such questions, but I am totally dumb when it comes to regexps and, if that, ready to wait to start a bounty) Thx)

Maybe it should be something like this:

```
string = 'a b c(a b c) d(a (b) c)'.relaceWhitespacesinParentheses('&wh;')

// 'a b c(a&wh;b&wh;c) d(a&wh;(b)&wh;c)'

string.split(' ')

// ['a', 'b', 'c(a&wh;b&wh;c)', 'd(a&wh;(b)&wh;c)']
```

Everything next is obvious

Comment: Regex in JS cannot handle nested parentheses. You are better off writing a parser

Comment: Is regex so necessary?

Comment: @vivek_23 No, it is necessary to complete task)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var str = 'a b d(a (b) c) c(a b c)   e(a (f t(o a i) ) ) ';
str = str.trim();
var result = [];
var open_bracket = 0;
var curr_str = '';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  if (str.charAt(i) === '(') open_bracket++;
  if (str.charAt(i) === ')') open_bracket--;

  if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    if (open_bracket == 0 && curr_str != '') {
      result.push(curr_str);
      curr_str = '';
    } else if (open_bracket > 0) {
      curr_str += str.charAt(i);
    }
  } else {
    curr_str += str.charAt(i);
  }
}

result.push(curr_str); // to include the last matched token.
console.log(result);
```

We move inside the string character by character. When we find a space, we see if we need to accommodate it in out result by checking if we have any brackets open. If yes, we append it to our temp result `curr_str`, else, we add the current `curr_str` to our results.

Comment: You are the hero! One problem I have now: @bobble bubble provided also a correct answer. But, honestly I simplified question, and there are really infinitive parentheses in my task. So I will use your solution. So, if his comment will get at least two upvotes, I'll remark your answer as correct

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this? There's probably a tidier way

```js
var string = 'a b c(a b c) d(a (b (a b c) d) c)'
var split = string.split(' ')

var numberOfBrackets = 0
var elements = []
split.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
  if (cur.includes('(')) {numberOfBrackets++}
  if (cur.includes(')')) {numberOfBrackets--}
  if (numberOfBrackets !== 0) {
    return acc + ' ' + cur
  } else {
    elements.push((acc + ' ' + cur).trim())
  }
  return ''
}, '')

console.log(elements)
```

Comment: I've tested this, unfortunately could not deal with 3 level parentheses `var string = 'a b c(a b c) d(a ((b) (c)))';` @vivek_23 solution can with infinitive

Answer (score 2):

If there is max one level of nesting you could try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hCDVsO/1).

```js
var str = 'a b c(a b c) d(a (b) c)';

var res = str.match(/\w+\([^)(]*(?:\([^)(]*\)[^)(]*)*\)|\S+/g);

console.log(res);
```

You'd need to add each level of deeper nesting to the pattern. Eg [with max two levels](https://regex101.com/r/hCDVsO/2/) ([fyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java/17759264#17759264)).

Comment: There is no way to specify infinitive nesting using regexp, right? I have a problem, your answer perfectly solves current question. But there are answers below without RegExp but covering infinitive nesting (actually my real life task has function call in function call). So can I ask you and community - is it ok if I mark them as accepted?

Comment: Another interesting thing) What would you do in my shoes?) Go learn `matchRecursive` or stay with some solutions below?)

Comment: @MaxCore I'm not here for reputation but for learning. Don't bother, just pick the answer that fits your task best :) I knew my answer only works for finite levels of nesting.

Comment: Should I forget about `matchRecursive` in this current task?)

Comment: The other people spent probably more time and effort writing that answers. Play with the API if you're interested, it's certainly useful for other tasks as well.