# How to find all ifs and ifs's condition with regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all if and if's condition
For example:
For this code:

```
if (bla === 3) {
}
if ((((ol === 1 || (true))))) {}
if ((1 === 4)
(this === 9)) {}
```

I want to get:

```
if (bla === 3)
```

```
if ((((ol === 1 || (true)))))
```

```
if ((1 === 4)
(this === 9))
```

I can make regex that find if, but my method have a problems: wrong work with a brakets(return "if ((some == some)", unclosed braket) or exits if and select unnecessary code.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in the general case using only native javascript RegExp, because matching nested parentheses requires a [more general parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529581/21146235). If you can live with a limited number of nested parens then [you can construct a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47484553/21146235) but it won't be particularly pretty.

Comment: @motto, you are assuming that the regex needs to test whether the parentheses are balanced, but the OP has not given that as a requirement. It could be known that the parentheses are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are confident that the parentheses and braces are balanced, so that needn't be tested, and that `'if'` always appears at the beginning of the string, you could match the following regular expression.

```
^if +\([^{]*\)(?= *\{)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DRs7st/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^          match beginning of string
if +\(     match 'if', then one or more spaces, then '('  
[^{]*      match zero or more characters other than '{'
\)         match ')'
(?= *\{)   positive lookahead asserts that match is followed by zero
           or more spaces followed by '{'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code syntax is always correct, there is always a `{` behind the if statement.

```
if [^{]+?(?={)
```

It will match the keyword `if`, a space after `if` to make sure its if keyword instead of some word starts with if, anything isnt `{` and followed by a `{`

- `if` : match keyword if followed by a space
- `[^{]+?`: match anything except for `{` and match as few as possible (`+?`)
- `(?={)`: possitive lookahead `{` to make sure match end with a `{`

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/8L8l0w/1)

If you dont want inline match (something like `else if (condition) {}`), considering add a start anchor `^` at the beginning of the regex!