# Regex: find string between curly brackets, which itself contains curly brackets

Tags: regex, string

Suppose a string on the following format:

```
Use \hyperlink{aaa}{apple {pear} banana} and \hyperlink{bbb}{banana {pear} {apple}}.
```

I want to extract:

```
\hyperlink{aaa}{apple {pear} banana}
\hyperlink{bbb}{banana {pear} {apple}}
```

What regex could be used for such an extraction?

I got stuck with this:

```
\\hyperlink{\S+}{.+}
```

Comment: Can there be arbitrary nesting? What language? See [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @bobblebubble what is meant by arbitrary nesting? I'm programming in Python

Comment: I meant if there can be deeper nesting than `{{}{}}` eg like `{{}{{}}}` for inifinite nesting you'd need a recursive regex. In Python it would be possible with a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no arbitrary nesting, you can use a pattern with [negated `}{`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) like

```
\\hyperlink{[^}{]*}{[^}{]*(?:{[^}{]*}[^}{]*)*}
```

Similar [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java/17759264#17759264) but [unrolled](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop). See [the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QoSnXW/3). To `{`extract`}` use [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoSnXW/2)).

Depending on your environment / regex flavor it can be necessary to escape the opening `{` by a backslash for the braces that are not inside a character class to match them literally.

Further note that `\S+` can consume `}` and [`.+` can match more than desired](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) if unaware.

Answer (score 2):

Here how you can do it with a recursive regex

```
\\hyperlink\{[^}]+?\}(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))+\})(?=\s|$)
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/tYaHGy/2/)

[`Recursive regex`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)